# Perl script to locate Visual Studio install

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that locates a Visual C install on a machine.  It works on a colleagues machine.  It fails on my machine.  I think it is because I have a different version of Visual Studio and it is installed in a different location.

Here is where I think it is failing

```
$needpath = 1;
$path   = $ENV{"PATH"};

if(grep(/VC/, $path)) {
  print "Found Visual C on path\n";
  $needpath = 0;
}
```

Q1. Can someone explain what $ENV{"PATH"}; is?  The grep function says it is a LIST.  A LIST of what?

Q2. My VS location is “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\”  Why can’t this script find it?

I’ve never used perl before.  Please be kind!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ENV{"PATH"}` is perl PATH environment variable. In your example `grep` filters list which size equals one, so same effect could be issued by

```
if ($path =~ /VC/) { .. }
```

It seems that your VS is not in the path, which can be checked from command line by `set path`

Comment: I was able to find a way to check the PATH environment variable by creating another perl script.  It had a lot of stuff in it, but not the /VC/ thus producing the failure.  So this solution explained $ENV and led me to the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 2010 and VS 2013 installed on my machine.
Have nothing in my path and I believe that visual studio works with relative path.
I think you need something similar like [this](http://blogs.perl.org/users/initself/2010/11/listing-all-installed-programs-in-windows-xp.html) to look at the installed software.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not update the `PATH` for a normal install. There are several command-line toolsets available in Visual Studio versions and some computers have two or more versions installed. These would lead to issues of which version should be placed in the `PATH`. To avoid this Visual Studio installs a number of shortcuts to command windows with the correct paths set for various purposes. These are written to the start menu folders for "**Visual Studio 2013\Visual Studio Tools**" and for "**Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools**".

To find the version(s) installed you may be better looking in the directories where the Visual Studio software is installed. Places such as `C:\Program Files` and similar.